# How can destructure object attribute？

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint

In ES6's grammar, I want to change the object 'fields' value. But ESlint detects an error

> 'Use array destructuring. (prefer-destructuring)'!

How can I destructure the following code?

`fields.classroomId = fields.classroomId[1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get clear how does destructuring work look at the code below:

```
const fields = {
 classroomid: [{ id: '1' },'text',100]
};
const { classroomid:[key1, key2, key3, key4] } = fields;
console.log(key1, key2, key3, key4); // { id: '1' } 'text' 100 undefined

//or

const { classroomid:[...keys] } = fields;
console.log(...keys); // { id: '1' } 'text' 100
```

**Hope it'll be useful for you**

Comment: With the help of you and reference some grammar of destructuring array, I have solved this problem! Thanks! This is my way:                                                       
  const formData = fields;                                                                                                      
  const {classroomId} = fields;                                                                                   
  ({1: formData.classroomId } = classroomId);